# How do I implement this line in my ASP.net MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");
    }
}
```

I want to add the Code"System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development"); to my program.cs file in my ASP.net MVC project. The code example was written with the old version of ASP.net MVC. The new version does not have a startup.cs. My question is how do I implement the code in my program.cs file that it completes the task.

Comment: See [Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). In the menu on the left, select the desired version.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in appsettings.json

```
"AppSettings": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
 }
```

if you are trying to use another version then what I had understood. refer to this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) here